# Why do I get extra zeros while OneHotEncoding categorical data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Coming straight from the Machine Learning course on Udemy, the lecture about Encoding categorical data has provided a CSV file to code-along.
The content of the file are fairly simple:
[image: Screenshot of the data]

Creating the matrix of features, I can get the data fairly easily with the values as it is.
But on using OneHotEncoder from sklearn (comlumn transformer), the "country column" split into 3 different column gives values as shown below:
[image: Screenshot of matrix of features]

The lecturer however, gets single decimal places for the same data and same code.
Can't seem to understand if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a change in version of the platform that is responsible for this.
How can I get the single decimal places instead of multiple zeros.

The code for encoding:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers =[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Edit:

Expected output for row 1:

```
[1.0 0.0 0.0 44.0 72000.0]
```

Output that I get:

```
[1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 4.40000000e+01 7.20000000e+04]
```

Comment: Hey, you can just show an example of you want and you get?
Im not sure if you want to have vectors that looks like that `[1,0,0]` or something else? Also, do you want to OneHot encode only the country column?

Comment: Hi, @Green 
Yes, thats exactly what I am hoping to get.
The lecturer gets:
[1.0 0.0 0.0 44.0 72000.0] 
for the column that has the data 
[France  44  72000]

Comment: I answered the previous thing. this is a bit different. Please edit the question so it would be clear.
Just give the exact input and output

Comment: Yes, sure!
I edited the question with the example

Comment: It's just a matter of how it gets displayed. `1.0` and `1.0000e+00` are both exactly the same data type and value.

Comment: You are completely right. The way he wrote the question confused  me...
now I see what he meant. @Swier
`7.20000000e+04 == 72000` etc.....

Comment: @Swier yes yes. Im really sorry for writing it that way. I just wanted the data to be displayed in the same manner. Thank you so much for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget everything I wrote.
just put this line if you want to see what happen...

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) #just to print nicely - you may remove it
```

I was completely confused by the question...